# CakePHP 3.0 get values on index.ctp instead id

Tags: php, cakephp, cakephp-3.0

I have two tables, 'applications' and 'statuses' where there is a relation 'applications' BelongsTo 'statuses'.
Lets begin with Model.

This is what **ApplicationsTable** looks like:

```
public function initialize(array $config)
{
    $this->table('applications');
    $this->displayField('title');
    $this->primaryKey('id');
    $this->addBehavior('Timestamp');
    $this->belongsTo('Users', [
        'foreignKey' => 'user_id',
        'joinType' => 'INNER'
    ]);

    $this->hasOne('Statuses', 
        'foreignKey' => 'status_id',
        'joinType' => 'INNER'
    ]);

    $this->belongsToMany('Statuses', [
        'foreignKey' => 'application_id',
        'targetForeignKey' => 'status_id',
        'joinTable' => 'applications_statuses'
    ]);
}
```

And **StatusesTable** looks like:

```
public function initialize(array $config)
{
    $this->table('statuses');
    $this->displayField('title');
    $this->primaryKey('id');
    $this->addBehavior('Timestamp');
    $this->hasMany('Applications', [
        'className' => 'Applications',
        'foreignKey' => 'status_id'
    ]);
}
```

This is what **ApplicationsController** for index looks like:

```
 public function index()
{
    $this->paginate = [
        'contain' => 'Users', 'Statuses'
    ];
    $this->set('applications', $this->paginate($this->Applications));
    $this->set('_serialize', ['applications', 'statuses']);
}
```

I want to show the titles of the status instead the id's on index.ctp

And here **index.ctp from Applications** look like:

```
<?php foreach ($applications as $application): ?>
    <tr>
        <td>
            <?= $application->has('user') ? $this->Html->link($application->user->name, ['controller' => 'Users', 'action' => 'view', $application->user->id]) : '' ?>
        </td>
        <td><?= $this->Html->link($application->title, ['action' => 'view', $application->id]) ?></td>
        <td><?= h($application->companyname) ?></td>
        <td><?= h($application->city) ?>, <?= h($application->country) ?></td>
        <td><?= h($application->status_id) ?></td> // **I want to get the titles of the status instead the id.**
        <td><?= h($application->modified) ?></td>
        <td class="actions">
            <?= $this->Html->link(__('Edit'), ['action' => 'edit', $application->id]) ?>
            <?= $this->Form->postLink(__('Delete'), ['action' => 'delete', $application->id], ['confirm' => __('Are you sure you want to delete # {0}?', $application->id)]) ?>
        </td>
    </tr>
```

**But I got always as the output the id**. I tried several ways:

```
1. <?= h($application->status_title) ?> // It doesn't work but it works for user

2. 'contain' => ['Users', 'Statuses'] // Change in ApplicationsController
<?= $application->has('status') ? $this->Html->link($application->status->title, ['controller' => 'Statuses', 'action' => 'view', $application->status->id]) : '' ?>

3. <td><?= h($application->status->title); ?></td>
```

Comment: can you show me what do you have in your index controller

Comment: hi Fury you can see my index controller now

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First of all your associations should use unique names, you cannot uses `Statuses` for the `belongsTo` as well as the `belongsToMany` association (same goes for `Applications`).

And then mind your syntax, the `Statuses` string is not being passed to the `contain` option, but is rather set as a value in the `paginate` options array

```
'contain' => 'Users', 'Statuses' // < it's on the same level as `contain`
```

It should be

```
'contain' => ['Users', 'Statuses']
```

And then this

```
<?= $application->has('status') ? $this->Html->link($application->status->title, ['controller' => 'Statuses', 'action' => 'view', $application->status->id]) : '' ?>
```

should work fine for the `belongsTo` association. The `belongsToMany` of course would need to be treated differently, as the property would hold an array.

Comment: I tried it already but it doesn't show anything. Thank you though

Comment: @sabianaragorn Then please add that to your question, so that people don't waste their time giving advices that you've already tried. Anyways, _this_ _is_ the way it needs to be done, so go from there.

Comment: IT WORKED!!!!!!!!!! It was a mistake in StatusesTable.. The relation to Applications was "belongsTo" and I changed it to "hasMany". And then I tried what you said.. and it works! Thanks, ndm!

Comment: It also worked with <?= $application->status->title ?>

Answer (score 0):

```
<?= h($application->status->title) ?>
```

PS: I would suggest putting a `__toString()` on your Status object, which returns the title. Then you can just do

```
<?= h($application->status) ?>
```

If you have:

```
function __toString(){
   return $this->title;
}
```

Comment: I already tried but I got error, Jessica. And where should I put those __toString function?

Comment: In the class that represents the Status object. What error did you get?

Comment: I tried your first advice with : <?= h($application->status->title) ?>  . 



And it says : "Notice (8): Trying to get property of non-object [APP/Template\Applications\index.ctp, line 31]"

Comment: So that means your application does not have a status.

Comment: Now I see you have it set up so one application can have many statuses. Did you mean for that to happen? Or did you want it to only have a single Status?

Comment: if I changed it $application->status_id, it shows the id. I want it to display the title not id.

Comment: No,  I didn't mean for that to happen. I want it to only have a single Status.. should I change the relation to hasOne?

Comment: I'm not super familiar with Cake honestly but that sounds right :) You'd call it "Status" not "Statuses"

Answer (score 0):

- First make sure you models are configured.

  ```
  // Remove this part from your model
  $this->hasOne('Statuses', 
      'foreignKey' => 'status_id',
      'joinType' => 'INNER'
  ]);

  // Replace it with
  $this->belongsTo('Statuses', [
      'foreignKey' => 'status_id',
      'joinType' => 'INNER'
  ]);
  ```
- In view you should be able to load your data like this:

  ```
  <td><?= h($application->status->title); ?></td>
  ```

The other would be an other solution:

- In your controller if you want to retrieve $statuses separately rather than paginating the $statuses try to do find()

  ```
  $this->set('statuses', statuses->find());
  ```

and then you can load the data in your view:

```
 <td><?= $statuses[$application->status_id][title]; ?></td>
```

Comment: I barely understand what you are suggesting here, fury.. where should I start? I can't add $statuses to index.ctp so easily. Where should I put those line to do find()?

Comment: Read the answer again. In order to view the data always you have to wrap your data ($this->Model->find()) in controller and pass it to view ($this->set('variables'))